# How to take all combination of a pandas dataframe (choosing 2 at a time) and make a new dataframe with each two combination in a single row?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, row, combinations

I have a Input dataframe as shown. Taking two rows at a time there are 4C2 combinations. I want the output to be saved in a dataframe as shown in output dataframe . In the output dataframe for each possible combination columns of two rows are side by side.

**Input df**

```
       A    B
 0    0.5   12
 1    0.7   16
 2    0.9   20
 3    0.11  24
```

---

**Output df**

```
 combination      A     B     A'   B'
   (0,1)        0.5    12   0.7   16
   (0,2)        0.5    12   0.9   20
   .................................
   .................................
```

Answer (score 4):

## Method 1

Create an artificial key column, then merge the `df` to itself:

```
df['key'] = 1

df.merge(df, on='key',suffixes=["", "'"]).reset_index(drop=True).drop('key', axis=1)
```

---

```
       A   B    A'  B'
0   0.50  12  0.50  12
1   0.50  12  0.70  16
2   0.50  12  0.90  20
3   0.50  12  0.11  24
4   0.70  16  0.50  12
5   0.70  16  0.70  16
6   0.70  16  0.90  20
7   0.70  16  0.11  24
8   0.90  20  0.50  12
9   0.90  20  0.70  16
10  0.90  20  0.90  20
11  0.90  20  0.11  24
12  0.11  24  0.50  12
13  0.11  24  0.70  16
14  0.11  24  0.90  20
15  0.11  24  0.11  24
```

## Method 2

First prepare a dataframe with all the possible combinations, then we merge our original dataframe to get the combinations side by side:

```
idx = [x for x in range(len(df))] * len(df)
idx.sort()
df2 = pd.concat([df]*len(df))
df2.index = idx

df.merge(df2, left_index=True, right_index=True, suffixes=["", "'"]).reset_index(drop=True)
```

---

```
       A   B    A'  B'
0   0.50  12  0.50  12
1   0.50  12  0.70  16
2   0.50  12  0.90  20
3   0.50  12  0.11  24
4   0.70  16  0.50  12
5   0.70  16  0.70  16
6   0.70  16  0.90  20
7   0.70  16  0.11  24
8   0.90  20  0.50  12
9   0.90  20  0.70  16
10  0.90  20  0.90  20
11  0.90  20  0.11  24
12  0.11  24  0.50  12
13  0.11  24  0.70  16
14  0.11  24  0.90  20
15  0.11  24  0.11  24
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's use `itertools.combinations`:

```
from itertools import combinations

pd.concat([df.loc[[i,j]]
             .unstack()
             .set_axis(["A","A'","B","B'"], axis=0, inplace=False)
             .to_frame(name=(i,j)).T 
            for i, j in combinations(df.index, 2)])
```

Output dataframe with multiindex:

```
       A    A'     B    B'
0 1  0.5  0.70  12.0  16.0
  2  0.5  0.90  12.0  20.0
  3  0.5  0.11  12.0  24.0
1 2  0.7  0.90  16.0  20.0
  3  0.7  0.11  16.0  24.0
2 3  0.9  0.11  20.0  24.0
```

Or as index with string

```
pd.concat([df.loc[[i,j]]
             .unstack()
             .set_axis(["A","A'","B","B'"], axis=0, inplace=False)
             .to_frame(name='('+str(i)+','+ str(j)+')').T 
           for i,j in combinations(df.index,2)]))
```

Output:

```
         A    A'     B    B'
(0,1)  0.5  0.70  12.0  16.0
(0,2)  0.5  0.90  12.0  20.0
(0,3)  0.5  0.11  12.0  24.0
(1,2)  0.7  0.90  16.0  20.0
(1,3)  0.7  0.11  16.0  24.0
(2,3)  0.9  0.11  20.0  24.0
```